# Memtable & key cache confusion

Tags: cassandra, hector, cql

I'm reading rows from a CF using Hector with the default Cassandra cache settings.
That means key cache is turned on. I am using jconsole to monitor the key cache hits.

But even after reading a single row (by a primary key) a 100 times, the cache hits does not increase. The row had been updated recently.

So when key cache is turned on what's the Cassandra read flow. Is it like this?

1. The in-memory MemTable is checked for the row (could reside there after a recent insert/update).
2. If not found in MemTable, the key cache is checked for the key.
3. If key found (cache hit), one seek , else 2 seeks to get the row.

But using `cassandra-cli` and `cassandra-jdbc` (CQL), I get different results.
That is, even when I have updated the row recently, each read from the row results in a key cache hit. Say, I read it a 100 times, I get 100 hits.

Why this discrepancy?

Well i kind of figured this out myself, but would like someone to confirm..

It looks like updates result in just fetching the column to be updated into the MemTable.
So when i updated a row using hector, i had not updated all the columns. Just a column `x` and was reading the same column `x` for the read operation. So no cache hit as its already in MemTable.

While running CQL , i was just running a `select * from cf` which resulted in fetching the other column `y` too. The column `y` had not been updated , so i am assuming it wouldn't have been in memory (MemTable) , hence resulting in the cache hit.

Answer (score 5):

Memtables and SSTables are always both checked when you read a row, and the results are merged together.  The key cache is only used for SSTables, not memtables (which are basically hashmaps).

If you write a new row and then read it shortly afterwards, the memtable probably will not have been flushed yet and will still hold the row.  Cassandra doesn't even have to look in the key cache in this case, because it can check the SSTable bloom filters quickly to see that the row isn't in any SSTables yet. So, in this case, the row data from the memtable is just returned directly.

If you force an early flush of the memtable (using nodetool) and then read the row a few times, you'll see that the key cache starts to get used.

Comment: Is this applicable for updates to the row too?

And is the data in the MemTable stored at the column level? I.e say after a MemTable flush, i update just one of the columns `x` in a row and read another column say `y` in the same row, then the key cache gets hit again since column `y` is not yet loaded into MemTable?

Comment: This should explain how it works: http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/MemtableSSTable.  Things don't move back into memtables; once you're reading anything from sstables, the key cache will be used.